# Prolog, understanding append/3

Tags: prolog, append

```
?- append([], [X1], [a,b]).
```

Why does this return `no` and not

```
X1 = a,b
```

Since

```
? - append([], [a,b], [a,b])
```

returns `yes`?

Comment: `[X1]` is a list of exactly one element, `X1`. So `append([], [X1], [a,b])` says `[a,b]` is the result of appending a single element list to the empty list, which will necessarily fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3)

```
append(?List1, ?List2, ?List1AndList2)
```

`List1AndList2` is the concatenation of `List1` and `List2`

---

So for

```
?- append([], [X1], [a,b]).
```

`[]` is the empty list and `[X1]` is a list with a variable `X1`

If you run the query like this

```
?- append([],[X1],A).
```

you get

```
A = [X1].
```

which means that `A` is the concatenation of `[]` and `[X1]`.

In your query it is asking if the concatenation of `[]` and `[X1]` is `[a,b]` which is false, or `no`.

---

For your second query

```
 ? - append([], [a,b], [a,b])
```

it is asking if the concatenation of `[]` and `[a,b]` is `[a,b]` which is true, or `yes`.

Answer (score 3):

To understand a Prolog program you have two choices:

- Think about the program as you do this in other programming languages by simulating the moves of the processor. This will lead to your mental exasperation very soon unless your name is Ryzen or in other words:

> You are a processor

- Let Prolog do the thinking and use Prolog to understand programs.

Whenever you see a failing goal, narrow down the reason why the goal fails by **generalizing** that goal (by replacing some term by a variable).  You do not need to understand the precise definition **at all**.  It suffices to try things out. In the case of your query

```
?- append([], [X1], [a,b]).
   false.
```

We have three arguments. Maybe the first is the culprit?  So I will replace it by a new variable:

```
?- append(Xs, [X1], [a,b]).
   Xs = [a], X1 = b
;  false.
```

Nailed it! Changing the first argument will lead to success. But what about the second argument?

```
?- append([], Ys, [a,b]).
   Ys = [a, b].
```

Again, culprit, too. And now for the third:

```
?- append([], [X1], Zs).
   Zs = [X1].
```

Verdict: All three kind-of guilty.  That is, it suffices to blame one of them.  Which one is up to you to choose.

Do this whenever you encounter a failing goal.  It will help you gain the relational view that makes Prolog such a special language.

And if we are at it. It often helps to consider **maximal failing generalizations**.  That is, generalizations that still fail but where each further step leads to success.  In your example this is:

```
?- append([], [X1], [a,b]).   % original query
   false.
?- append([], [_], [_,_|_]).  % maximal failing generalization
   false.
```

From this you can already draw some conclusions:

1. The lists' elements are irrelevant.
2. Only the length of the three lists is of relevance
3. The third list needs to be two elements or longer.